# How to link the ZK form with submit button

Tags: java, forms, form-submit, zk

I'm new in zk ,I have a form with field and I defined some constraint on those fields and a submit button ,who can I link the submit button with the form and fields ,so I want click on the button the fields where the constraint not satisfied will appear in red ,Now my button doesn't see if the constraint are satisfied ,I know that I could verify in java code but that will not make the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MVC you could check componant if there are all validate before submitting
here a good code it's helpful and good luck

[here is the code](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1o3ojpi/2-Force-validation-of-constraints-before-processing-the-form)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example on [zk fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3h1kh80/2-MVVM-confirm-case) of how you do it in MVVM.

You need to work with `@load` and `@save` seperated so you can tell to save before the command.
When your constraint fails the `@command` is never fired.

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('pkg$.VM')">
    <hbox>
        <textbox value="@load(vm.name) @save(vm.name,before='register')" constraint="no empty" />
        <label value="@load(vm.name)" />
    </hbox>
    <hbox>
        <button label="register" onClick="@command('register')" />
    </hbox>
</window>
```

**Edit : For MVC**

You'll find in the [zk documentation a very nice description with example](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials/Chapter_5%3a_Handling_User_Input) of how to make constraints in mvc.

Comment: Is there some other exemple with MVC ?

Comment: Monday I'll make a nice one for you. The ones I find are not nice examples